# Pasado perfecto de subjuntivo o indicativo

Tags: subjuntivo

I need to use "pasado perfecto de subjuntivo" or "pasado perfecto de indicativo".

I have three sentences with possible choices.

Choices: sido, tomado, pasado, cambiado, tratado, tenido, conocido, podido, progresado, hablado.

1. Como su hermano era la persona menos ecológica que Claribel **__** en su vida, a ella le gustaba muchísimo que por fin él hubiera tomado la decisión de intentar respetar más el medio ambiente.
2. Ahora que habían pasado unas semanas, quería ver cómo ***_*__** .
3. No creía que **__** posible que hubiera cambiado todos sus hábitos.

For 1, I tried to use "hubiera sido" and "había sido", but both are wrong.
For 2, I tried to use "hubiera progresado" and "hubiera cambiado".
For 3, I tried to use "hubiera progresado" and "hubiera podido".

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1=habia conocido

2=habia cambiado

3=hubiera sido

Comment: The second one is "había progresado", pero muchas gracias para sus respuestas. : ))

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que no estaba entre tus opciones pero la 3) suena mucho mejor así

3) No creía que **fuera** posible que hubiera cambiado todos sus hábitos.